# Time taken by loop/commands in usecs in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, unix-timestamp

I need to measure the time taken by command(s) in usecs inside my shell script

```
start_time ;
Command1;
command2;
end_time;

time_taken = end_time -start_Time;
```

I was looking at the Time commands, but not sure how to capture in usecs and subtract the end and start times. Can someone please assist .

Comment: The bash `time` builtin is only in msecs. For usecs you'd need to call an external command that will take a few msecs to be forked, rendering it meaningless to use that precision.

Answer (score 3):

**Before You Use This:** Consider if you *really* need µs precision. Shells are not made for writing performant code, so timing them that precisely seems somewhat strange. I can only think of one valid usecase: Measuring the performance of pure bash statements  / builtins (without having to tinker with its source code, profilers, and so on). For that case, also remember to repeat your measurements 10'000 times or so, to ensure that they aren't dominated by noise on your system. Additionally, you can also measure the empty script and subtract its measurements from yours.

---

With bash 5 or higher, you can use the built-in variable `EPOCHREALTIME` which always contains the current unixtime (in seconds) with a fractional part down to µs precision. Since the fractional part has a fixed number of decimal places, you can simply remove the `.` to convert it to µs.

```
start_time=$EPOCHREALTIME
echo "execute some commands here"
end_time=$EPOCHREALTIME

(( time_taken = ${end_time/./} - ${start_time/./} ))
declare -p time_taken
```

If you really need this for older bash versions (e.g. mac OS' ancient bash 3) you have to write your own builtin (basically a bash plugin if you will) and [`enable`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-enable) it. Look at [bash's source code](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/). It comes with a a few examples for user-written builtins.

Comment: if you use `start_time=${EPOCHREALTIME/./}` then you won't need to expand any variable in the arithmetic expansion: `(( time_taken = end_time - start_time ))` (not that it matters much)

Comment: @Fravadona I know. Your suggestion was even my first version. But then I realized that the expansion `${var/.../...}` would take considerably more time than just `$var`. That would defeat the point of measuring µs. Therefore I delayed as much of the work as possible.